# Minimum midl-generated files needed for local-process only COM object?

Tags: c++, winapi, com, idl, midl

I'm making a COM interface, `ITest` which is part of a test suite running only in a local process. The particular functionality I'm testing is not important but the main point is I will not be using `CoCreateInstance()` or any factory objects to instantiate the backing object and get a pointer to the interface. I will simply call a trivial function that looks like this:

```
HRESULT InstantiateTestObject(ITest ** pptest);
```

Obviously, I only need a fairly minimal subset of the whole functionality provided by COM.

With that in mind, here's my question.

I understand you can use `nul` as a way of telling `midl` not to generate a particular file (*e.g.*`midl itest.idl /iid nul` to suppress generating the IID file). If I only plan to instantiate the object backing my `ITest` interface via the trivial function shown above, and I only plan to use it in the local process, what is the smallest subset of `midl` output files I actually need?

Comment: If you don't need cross-apartment marshaling, then you don't need an IDL file at all. Just define your interface in an .h file.

Comment: The reason I'm using an IDL file (maybe I'm wrong here?) is `ITest` is actually an `IDispatch`-supporting dual interface (*i.e.* `[dual, local, ...] interface ITest : IDispatch`) and I want `midl` to generate the TLB file which I need to simplify my implementation of `IDispatch`. Does this make sense?

Comment: Well, then yes, you would want an IDL definition. If I recall correctly, if you put your interface definition inside the `library{}` block, then MIDL won't generate *_i.{h,c} files - only the TLB file and the .h file with the interface definition.

Comment: That actually worked perfectly for my purposes. I put my interface inside the `library` block and it spat out only the TLB. If you run it with the /h switch it will also generate the header. Thanks! Do you want to put your comment in an answer? If so I'll accept it.